# How to perform multilevel aggregation in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

I have the below collections

```
PaymentStatus   Amount  Receipt
-------------   ------  ---------
Status1         450     123
Status1         54      777
Status2         1230    234
Status2         67      12
Status3         3452    235
Status3         11111   678
Status4         678     156
Status5         346     12
Status5         1000    7
Status6         2000    753
```

I need to perform a group by in such a way so that the result set will be as under

```
CollectionUnit  MoneyCollected  NoOfReceipt
--------------- --------------  -------------
Unit1               504             2
Unit2               15860           4
Unit3               678             1
Unit4               3346            3
```

**The definitions of the CollectionUnit**

```
Unit1 who falls in the Status1
Unit2 who falls in the Status2 and Status3
Unit3 who falls in the Status4
Unit4 who falls in the Status5 and Status6
```

**MoneyCollected = Sum(Amount)**

**NoOfReceipt = Count(Receipt)**

I have been able to perform the first level of aggregation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  

           var paymentCollections = new List<Payment>() {
                new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status1", Amount=450, Receipt=123 },
                new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status1", Amount=54, Receipt=777 },
                new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status2", Amount=1230, Receipt=234 },
                 new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status2", Amount=67, Receipt=12 },
                 new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status3", Amount=3452, Receipt=235 },
                new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status3", Amount=11111, Receipt=678 },
                new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status4", Amount=678, Receipt=156 },
                 new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status5", Amount=346, Receipt=12 },
                  new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status5", Amount=1000, Receipt=7 },
                   new Payment { PaymentStatus= "Status6", Amount=2000, Receipt=753 }
            };

            //level 1 aggregation
            var result = paymentCollections.GroupBy(l => l.PaymentStatus)
                        .Select(cl => new MoneyMovement
                        {
                            CollectionUnit = cl.First().PaymentStatus,
                            MoneyCollected = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount).ToString(),
                            NoOfReceipt = cl.Count().ToString(),
                        }).ToList();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Payment
    {
        public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public float Amount { get; set; }
        public int Receipt { get; set; }
    }

    public class MoneyMovement
    {
        public string CollectionUnit { get; set; }

        public string MoneyCollected { get; set; }

        public string NoOfReceipt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: since you don't have table for Unit-Status relation you have to do this with bunch of if/switch ... where is the problem? pseudo code `result.ForEach(s=>switch(s.CollectionUnit) { case "Status1"  Unit1Sum += s.MoneyCollected; Unit1Recs += s.NoOfReceipt; break; case "Status2": case "Status3": .... and so on ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by your conditions. ie:

```
//level 1 aggregation
var result = paymentCollections
            .GroupBy(l => new
            {
                Unit = l.PaymentStatus == "Status1"
                ? "Unit1"
                : l.PaymentStatus == "Status2" || l.PaymentStatus == "Status3"
                ? "Unit2"
                : l.PaymentStatus == "Status4"
                ? "Unit3"
                : l.PaymentStatus == "Status5" || l.PaymentStatus == "Status6"
                ? "Unit4"
                : "Unknown"
            })
            .Select(cl => new MoneyMovement
            {
                CollectionUnit = cl.Key.Unit,
                MoneyCollected = cl.Sum(c => c.Amount).ToString(),
                NoOfReceipt = cl.Count().ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Selvin, I don't think so but it is in the eye of beholder.

Comment: For readability, I'd have the conversion (status to unit) in a separate method, perhaps even another class.  Definitely in the eye of the beholder.  Good answer imo.

Comment: A switch could not be translated to SQL. That is not opinion based, that's a fact. Also separation in different classes would prevent the use with SQL sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want faster code, avoid Linq and just use a loop

```
   Dictionary<string, int> Status = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
   {"Status1", 0},
   {"Status2", 1},
   {"Status3", 1},
   {"Status4", 2},
   {"Status5", 2},
   {"Status6", 3}};

    var Units = new string[] { "Unit1", "Unit2", "Unit3", "Unit4" };

    MoneyMovement[4] movements = new MoneyMovement[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        movements[i] = new MoneyMovement() { CollectionUnit = Units[i] };

    foreach(var item in paymentsCollection)
    {
        var m = movements[Status[item.PaymentStatus]];
        m.MoneyCollected += item.Amount;
        m.NoOfReceipt++;
    }
```

This way you avoid a lot of multiple enumerations and iterations, LINQ is doing by design.

Also try to avoid these many strings. I assume here MoneyCollected or NoOfReceipt could become a double or decimal. Also things like Status or Unit look like they would be better designed with an enum.